# I want to display data from API, but I don't want to use multiple *ngIfs? Is there another way?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the **Reason** property from API, and it has different values. For each specific value I have to display the corresponding value from the table below. But I don't want to use multiple ngIfs, can I do it with mapping or maybe another way?

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtHfF.png)

Comment: Have you looked into ngSwitch? (https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

Answer (score 0):

You can store data from the TABLE in Map object:

```
const tableMap = new Map([
  ['NOT_ELIGIBLE', 'RX not Eligible'],
  ['YES_ELIGIBLE', 'Approved']
]);
```

To display a corresponding value:

```
tableMap.get('NOT_ELIGIBLE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Even don't have to be very fancy. You can acheive it with simple approach.
You can have an enum like this

```
export enum StatusValues{
 NOT_ELIGIBLE = 'Rx Not Eligible'
 YES_ELIGIBLE = 'Yes Eligible'
}
```

and then in your template you can do like this

```
<p>{{StatusValues[yourResponseKey]}}</p>
```

There is no need to use `ngIf`, `ngSwitch`